# Как выдавать роли определенные права (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Как выдавать созданной роли в discord права?
Киньте ссылку на источник, где это все подробно рассказано?
ps искал в интернете, но нашел только как задавать цвет...

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions не про права, разве?

Comment: документация полностью на Англиском, а я его лишь изучаю, я врятли там что-то пойму

Comment: почитав немного документацию так и ничего не понял

Comment: переводчики запретили?)

Comment: они переводят криво, и часть они не переводят вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найдите роль через

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id = {roleid}) #через айди будет проще искать
```

Далее, изменяем её.

```
await role.edit(*, reason = "None", **fields)
```

Что можно изменить, вы можете найти в [Документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role.edit).

Comment: возможно я слишком тупой, но делал все вот так `await role.edit(reason = "None", administrator = True)` и ничего не вышло, ошибок не выдает, просто не даються никакие права

Comment: Вы права должны указывать (насколько я помню) в словаре:
permissions = {Здесь нужные права}.
Опять же - обращайтесь к документации.

Comment: Извиняюсь, вот правильный вариант - `perms = discord.Permissions(administrator = True)`
Далее, уже в функции edit() указываем параметр `permissions = perms`